# Android shake bug in coordinatorLayout scrolling with recyclerview (also instagram have this bug)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

scrolling on `CoordinatorLayout` and scroll down on `RecyclerView` Shakes. this is big bug also on instagram and still not fixed :|

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent">

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please look at the GIF to see this bug on instagram: (gif size is 11MB. please wait to load complete)

http://uupload.ir/files/ree5_animation.gif

Comment: Do you know if this is still an issue? I had never seen it before on my app until this year. I also tried to look at your animation but it's been taken down since publication. Any chance you still have it?

Comment: @kriztho No. This problem is still not fixed in android and androidx developers do not pay attention to it. in `CoordinatorLayout`, when scrollup on `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and immediately scrolldown on `RecyclerView` It leads to this vibration UI.